# jQuery Validation dynamic key Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

A newbie to jQuery. I am attempting use an array to auto populate elements for form validation. For some reason `data.result[1].form_field` leads to an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." error.

```
    var $Form = $("#form").validate({

        // Rules for form validation
        rules : {
            data.result[1].form_field : {
                required : true,
                range: [data.result[1].minimum, data.result[1].maximum]
            }
        },

        // Do not change code below
        errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        }
    });
```

Strangly, if I directly write in the field name things work fine.

```
    var $Form = $("#form").validate({

        // Rules for form validation
        rules : {
            some_field : {
                required : true,
                range: [data.result[1].minimum, data.result[1].maximum]
            }
        },

        // Do not change code below
        errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        }
    });
```

Not sure why `data.result[1].minimum, data.result[1].maximum` work, but `data.result[1].form_field` does not.

Comment: Is data.result defined somewhere above this? and what does the data structure look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining the rules like so if its a dynamic key you cant declare it like that...

```
var specificRules = { rules: {} };

specificRules.rules[ data.result[1].form_field ] = {
     required : true,
     range: [data.result[1].minimum, data.result[1].maximum]
}

var $Form = $("#form").validate( specificRules );
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. Your answer worked like a charm, however, in my original question I left some code out as I though it would make my question more easy to read. I'm not sure how to fit this additional code in your solution. Also can your solution be used in a for loop? I would like to use `$.each(data.result, function (index, item) {` to populate all fields.

Comment: Something like this? This won't run obviously because im not including the validate plugin but the syntax should be right... http://jsfiddle.net/eL1vmf4t/

Comment: Works for the first field in my array, however, not for subsquent fields. I think that `$qaForm.validate( currentRuleSet );` needs to be out of the loop. First the list of rules must be built before validate.

Comment: Not sure what the plugin expects as far as syntax for multiple fields. If you tell me the plugin I could tell

Comment: I've added an example of the plugin syntax. Note this is an example from some random form, but it should give you an idea of what the plugin is looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/eL1vmf4t/3/

Comment: Not sure why, but it seems that `$('#checkout-form').validate( formRuleSet );` must be ran from inside the loop...? This works for some reason http://jsfiddle.net/61nygss5/2/

Comment: Hmm that doesnt make sense. So what the loops intention is to create the rules/message struct dynamically based on data that was retrieved elsewhere I'm assuming like a database table right or some model? So basically what the .each is doing is iterating and dynamically generating the 2 structs required for loading the validation. It literally is a direct translation into a dynamic build of the sample syntax you sent in the previous fiddle.

Comment: Why do you think this needs to be run inside the loop? Also this should be done for each form type

Comment: I tried using your fiddle data array and things worked fine. There must be something wrong with my JSON array formatting... Anyways, I totally appreciate your time and effort in going above and beyond my original question in helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ."

The "unexpected token" is the first dot in the field name.

[As per documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#fields-with-complex-names-(brackets-dots)), you must enclose field names in quotes when they contain brackets or dots...

```
var $Form = $("#form").validate({    
    rules : {
        "data.result[1].form_field": {
            required: true,
            range: [data.result[1].minimum, data.result[1].maximum]
        }
    },
    ....
```